# integrating jenkins with salesforce with svn as code repository

Tags: jenkins, ant-script

**Error message:**

> Unable to find build script at C:\Users.jenkins\workspace\sfdc\https:\url\svn\svn_test\branches\Enhancement\build.xml
>   Finished: FAILURE

I am having issues when integrating jenkins with salesforce. I developed a basic version of ANT build.xml script to retrieve from an org. What is specified in package.xml and build.properties and my svn location url has below folders in svn repo location: https://url/svn/svn_test/branches/Enhancement

Package folder - this has package.xml which says to pull just one class
build.xml
build.properties

**my build.xml is as below:**

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">
  <property file="build.properties"/>
  <property environment="env"/>
  <target name="retrieveCode">
    <mkdir dir="retrieveOutput"/>
    <!-- Retrieve the contents into directory CHANGE retrieveTarget (the directory where retrieved files will be saved TO MATCH YOUR ENVIRONMENT-->
    <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" retrieveTarget="retrieveOutput" unpackaged="package/package.xml"/>
  </target>

  <target name="deployCode">
    <!-- Upload the contents of the "trunk" directory, CHANGE deployRoot TO MATCH YOUR environment-->
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" deployRoot="retrieveOutput"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: The error message says Jenkins can't find the script. Double check where it is in your SVN tree and where you are telling Jenkins it is.

Comment: my repository location is https://svn-name.com/svn/svn_test/branches/Enhancement and so is my build.xml https://svn-name.com/svn/svn_test/branches/Enhancement and i am just trying to retrieve for that matter i.e target "retrieveCode"